# Is a function containing a "limit" of a CDF continuous?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, continuity

Suppose we have a function
$$
f(x) = 1-\alpha F^-(x)
$$
Where $F^-$ is the left limit of a CDF.

In general is $f(x)$ not continuous? Is it possible for $f(x)$ to be continuous if $F$ is not?

What if $F$ is continuous (so $F(x) =F^-(x))$?. Then $f(x)$ should be continuous as the composition of continuous functions correct?

---

I guess my confusion is that $F^-$ is not $F$. hence I don't know how I should "think about" this function.

That is, if $F$ is discontinuous it has jumps (or maybe some other weirdness, but maybe not because CADLAG, I'm not sure) so in general $g(x) = 1-\alpha F(X)$ is not continuous. But I don't know if $F^-$ has jumps (or some other weirdness), or if I am overlooking something

Comment: If $F$ has jumps then so does $F^{-}$.  If you define $G(y)=1-F^{-}(-y)$ then it should be obvious $G$ is a cdf when $F$ is

Comment: @Henry Why did you bring up $G$? (That is, I don't see the relevance of $G$. -- I do see it is a CDF). Also, Thank you for helping me at both my questions.

Comment: $F$ is right continuous,i.e. $F^{+} = F$ right?

Comment: @BCLC yes, of course.

Comment: I was trying to convince you that $F^{-}$ had jumps if $F$ did by showing you $F^{-}$ was a cdf backwards

Comment: If alpha = 0 then?